# WouldBlock is passed to ReceiveAsync callback

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, unity-game-engine, mono

I use non-blocking send and ReceiveAsync for receiving.

```
var r = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
r.Completed += _receiveArgs_Completed;
r.SetBuffer(new byte[chunkSize], 0, chunkSize);

Client.Client.ReceiveAsync(r); // return value check omitted

void _receiveArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.WouldBlock)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Async receive would block, wtf? " + Environment.StackTrace);
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

With MS .NET it runs fine but in Unity (which uses Mono 2.6) it gets WouldBlock.

BeginReceive works but it has other problems so I want to try ReceiveAsync.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use non-blocking and asynchronous together. It's pointless. Asynchronous is already inherently non-blocking, and works fine on its own.

If you set the socket to non-blocking, then *every* attempt to receive will complete immediately. Either with data, or with `SocketError.WouldBlock`.

Frankly, no .NET program should ever use non-blocking sockets. The only way to use non-blocking sockets correctly is to poll the socket, and polling is wasteful and unnecessary, given the good support for asynchronous operations that .NET offers.

Comment: But why not, it works in .NET! "It's pointless" - I have my reasons. In my case non-blocking send works better (with .NET). MSDN doesn't forbid to use async API with non-blocking together. Technically it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: By .NET I meant MS.NET

Comment: No. There's no reason to expect this to work on Windows. That it does is pure good luck on your part. The Mono behavior is actually "more correct" per the socket spec. If it works at all on .NET, it's highly unlikely that setting the socket to non-blocking had any effect at all, never mind "works better" (but feel free to post a different question if you think otherwise and want help with that). For your specific question here, the solution is to simply stop setting the socket to non-blocking.

Comment: My reasons: BeginSend *can* block if send buffer is full. This is *critical* for server. With non-blocking send I have the same async behavior but also I have a full control over the situation where the send buffer becomes filled. Instead of blocking I just get an exception and note somewhere to retry later. And it looks like it really work with async API together in MS .NET...

Comment: And I can't use polling for receive, it makes roundtrip time absolutely horrible.

Comment: Yes, you certainly shouldn't use polling, as I wrote. As for `BeginSend()` truly blocking, I've never heard of that happening, it's not documented as happening, and I doubt it can happen. With a non-blocking socket, using IOCP, the underlying Winsock API will still return, but with the error WSAEWOULDBLOCK if you attempt too many overlapped operations. I used `BeginSend()` to an unresponsive remote host, and while things started to slow down at around 40MB of sent data, it never actually blocked. And looking at the implementation of `BeginSend()`, there's nothing in there that could block.

Comment: Another reason is performance. My test for 16000 active clients shows these results: non-blocking send - 33% CPU, 70 ms reply time;  BeginSend - 40% CPU, 100 ms reply time. Means something, yeah?

Comment: SendAsync performs better - 34% CPU, 95 ms reply time. Of course without my system information these tests are only applicable for techniques comparsion. But non-blocking Send still shows much metter results in server reply time.

Comment: I made it work nearly as good as non-blocking send. I'll accept this answer.